# Multiple instances of axwindowsmediaplayer and only one allowing full screen mode

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

My application spawns multiple instances of `axWindowsMediaPlayer` (one per form). When playing one file, setting to full screen isn't an issue however, when playing 2 files (with a media player per monitor) it won't allow both to go into full screen mode (the option is greyed out in the context menu on the second video and error's when I try setting it in code).

Is this a limitation of `axwindowsmediaplayer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work out a work around for this but will not mark this as an answer unless I don't get any other feedback as I still feel this is cheating a little.

Rather than using the `wmPlayer.fullScreen` property. Do this instead:

```
wmPlayer.Height = this.Height; //this being the form
wmPlayer.Width = this.Width;
wmPlayer.stretchToFit = true;
```